# how to watch akka actor and capture its context in the Terminated message receive

Tags: scala, akka, actor

I want to supervise child actors using `context.watch(childActor)` API

I see that when the child actor has an uncaught exception, indeed the receive message "Terminated" is called on the parent.

But since I am creating many children actors, each with different contexts and messages, I don't know which particular child actor (and surrounding context) actually failed.

For example:

```
class ParentActor extends Actor {
  override def receive = {
    case "delegateWorkToChildrenActors" => {
       (0 to 100) foreach {
        i =>
          val child = context.actorOf(Props(new ChildActor(i, "child-actor")
          context.watch(child)
          val message = SomeSortOfComplexMessageWithManyParameters(...)
          val res = child ? message
          res.onComplete {
            x: Try[Any] => x match {
      case Failure(exception: Throwable) => // can only get timeout exception here
      case Success(value) => // continue as usual
    }
          }
      }
    }
   case m @ Terminated(actor) => {

      // a child actor was terminated but what is its context ? i.e. which message did it try to handle ?
    }
  }
  override val supervisorStrategy = OneForOneStrategy(maxNrOfRetries = 1, withinTimeRange = 1 minute) {

    case m @ _ => {
      Stop // Assume that the actor was stopped or crashed etc.
    }
  }
}

class ChildActor(number : Int) extends Actor {
override def receive: Receive = {
  case SomeSortOfComplexMessageWithManyParameters => {
     // might of got some sort of exception here...
     // the parent which is monitoring it received the "Terminate" message
  }
}
}
```

How can I get the message that the child actor worked upon?

Comment: You can have an id member variable inside of ChildActor and then when you pass the number to ChildActor, that time you can set that value.

Comment: The actors are being reused and that would require a massive refactor. I need a holistic solution to this problem that is rampant. It is a general problem that should have a simple solution IMO